# Multi-language app by singleton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, multilingual

I want to convert my app to support multiple languages. I want make to make settings for switching languages. Is there a good way to make a Singleton class for getting strings and images? I don't want localization from iPhone, but localization for application, if that makes sense... Thx for reply!

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is good (and I've seen it implemented this very way for many applications). You need a basic singleton class that will implement a dictionary and will return the correct string when asked for the name of a localized string.

At a bare minimum, you'll probably need

some constructor to read in the localized strings.

a method setLanguage(String language) to set the current localized language.

a method getLocalizedString:(String field) to get the localized string for the current language.

Here's a basic implementation of the header:

```
@interface LocalizedString : NSObject

+ (void)setLanguage(String language);
+ (void)getLocalizedStringForField(String field);

static current_language;

@end
```