# Handling multi language from Singleton class

Tags: java, android, singleton, multilingual

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884900/multi-language-app-by-singleton) I can see that handling multi language from Singleton is possible with objective C. I hope it can also be done from Java.

I want something like, when the user selects the language from spinner then the selected language should be set as a current language. And that current language is retrieved in the all the activities using get method. Is it possible to do? If yes, how?

This is what I have done so far;

My Singleton Class;

```
public class SharedMemory {

private String currentLanguage;

private static SharedMemory instance;

private SharedMemory() {

}

public static SharedMemory getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new SharedMemory();
    return instance;

}

public String getCurrentLanguage() {
    return currentLanguage;
}

public void setCurrentLanguage(String currentLanguage) {
    this.currentLanguage = currentLanguage;
}
```

My base activity class;

```
public class Base_Activity extends Activity {

private String currentLanguage;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.getItem(0).getActionView()
            .findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.languages, R.layout.spinner_row);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            currentLanguage = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Log.i("Seted Language", currentLanguage);
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                // do nothing
                break;

            case 1:
                setLocale("en_US");
                break;

            case 2:
                setLocale("fi");
                break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

        }

    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void setLocale(String currentLanguage) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(currentLanguage);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    recreate();
    SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentLanguage(currentLanguage);

}
 }
```

But here, the language is changed from the Locale which I do not want.

Comment: So basically you want to change your language in your code without depending on user's locale?

Comment: Exactly. IS that possible?

Comment: @Android-Developer . Dude Do you have any solutions to assets me.

Answer (score 0):

I do this using the SharedPreferences:

```
        String firstLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString().substring(0, 2);
        String currentLocale  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("locale", firstLocale);
        Locale locale = new Locale((String) currentLocale);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();


      config.locale = locale;
      Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

And it works fine in my app.

Comment: dude. What's wrong in my code. When I call to the activities using SharedMemory.getInstance.getCurrentLanguage. It crashes saying NullPointerException.

Comment: Well I don't know what getCurrentTraining is but since you're nullsafing the getInstance() operation my guess is that you're calling getCurrentTraining() without properly initializing the training variable first.

Comment: sorry. I edited my comments. Actually I was trying to write currentLanguage.

Comment: Which line exactly are you getting the nullpointerexception. Please post your logcat.

Comment: No I was checking that using Log.i in Activity class which has extension of this Base_Activity class.

Comment: Post your LogCat stackTrace and then we can see the problem.

Comment: In MainActivity class I have System.out.println(SharedMemory.getInstance().getCurrentLanguage()); just to check if I can get something. In that case, I got 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packageName.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: When you call that and try to print it you have not yet initialized that variable. That is my best guess, given that you won't post your LogCat output.

Comment: Do not know how to post all the logcat :(

Comment: Just copy what your logcat says and then post it on your original question.